# Quickly deduce block (s, p, d ...) from atomic number

Tags: periodic-trends, periodic-table

A question from previous year papers of IIT JEE. There's not enough time to write the electronic configuration in the exam. Please suggest a quick, objective approach. [image: Photo of exam question]

Comment: Need you to show your workings fast, please.  We have to see where you need help in this problem.

Comment: If you don't want to write the electronic configurations, have a reference point (usually noble gases). For example, knowing that atomic number of Xenon is 54, atomic number 55 would have to be from s-block.

Answer (score 3):

Other than memorizing (and writing down for visualization) some atomic numbers, I cannot think of how to do this. I suggest the atomic numbers of the noble gases for this, which are: $\ce{He}$ 2, $\ce{Ne}$ 10, $\ce{Ar}$ 18, $\ce{Kr}$ 36, $\ce{Xe}$ 54, $\ce{Rn}$ 86. (Since noble gases are kool with a k, one should know them anyway. Use a mnemonic, if necessary.)

Then, one finds:

- 55 is one above $\ce{Xe}$, so s-block.
- 45 is nine down from 54, that is surely d-block.
- 81 is five down from 86, that is p-block (barely).
- 64 ten up from 54, that is f-block.

Comment: I have another question.How do you calculate the magnetic moment of Hg2+?I know the formula,but again-you need the unpaired electrons for which EC is necessary.What should i do here?

Comment: @GKA Comments are not for unrelated questions.

Comment: It wouldn't let me ask another question,anyway this is kind of related to electronic configuration isn't it?